# Reasons for using readable SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

The Android class SQLiteOpenHelper has a method to return a readable database as well as a read and writable database. Currently I am only using writable database and have no issues but I am wondering what the benefit would be to change to using readable only if I am only reading in an async task (or activity).

There might be performance benefits but I have not seen any reference to actual numbers. Also if I keep switching between readable and writable the change has an overhead that might take all the performance advantage away.

Does anybody have any real numbers or experience with this? Is it worth implementing separate access?

Comment: I have generally interpreted it as a protection measure more so than performance. One could declare all Java classes/methods/data members public, but we use `protected`, `private`, and package-`protected` to prevent ourselves from screwing up. Similarly, a readable database might help catch coding errors. That being said, since `SQLiteOpenHelper` transparently "upgrades" the database to writable on a future `getWritableDatabase()` call, the value is probably somewhat limited.

Comment: Thanks for that hint. I think I am going to not bother at this stage as mentioned below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't comment on performance benefits but I always try to work on the principle of 'good practice' (or 'best practice' even) for any access to any 'data' sources (text files, DBs or whatever).

Looking at things generically (not Android specific), the decisions to be made when deciding on access level, come down to the operation to be performed as well as any outside influences.

Two examples I can think of...

1. If an external process may have the
   responsibility of maintaining data -
   in this case it may have 'opened'
   the data source in such a way that
   it blocks all but 'read' access by
   any other process during the maintenance phase. In this case,
   your code will be denied access if
   you request read/write access when
   it isn't necessary.
2. The risk of compromising data integrity - hacks into systems from the outside world can be achieved via a security hole using internal code which has read/write access to data when it really only needed to have 'read' access.

OK, those points may or may not have relevance to Android (particularly if your data source is specific to your app) but, as I said, I try to look at things generically and use a 'best practice' approach. If I don't need 'write' access, I don't request it.

Comment: While I agree with your points they dont apply to Android in this instance. There is no db server as such, but rather a unique db file and access code (naitve and via dalvik vm) that is unique to this application. Within each app the db access is exclusive (enforced) and sequential. If another app has a db it is a separate db file and exections for access and all (each app has its own vm). Also as you saw above in the other comment the javadoc even says that the same object is returned so it all makes even less sense..

Comment: @Manfred Moser : Yes, I'm aware that apps exists within thier own vm and I'm quite familiar with SQLite having no server (I've been using SQLite for a while now on various platforms). Do all SQLite dbs exist 'in-process' however? What about those that may be created on SD card for example? Also, what about access from other threads within the same app? The comment from CommonsWare about we don't create everything as 'public' was basically what I meant - 'best practice' and all that. Never assume your 'arena' will never change.

Comment: I am going to accept your answer at this stage. At this stage I doubt that I will make the effort to refactor it since in my case I think the constant closing and opening would be reducing performance. In terms of protection I see no value since it the data is non critical.

Answer (score 6):

Good question. No numbers from me. The nearest explanation (from SQLLiteOpenHandler javadoc)

> "This(getReadableDatabase) will be the same object returned by getWritableDatabase() unless some problem, such as a full disk, requires the database to be opened read-only. In that case, a read-only database object will be returned. If the problem is fixed, a future call to getWritableDatabase() may succeed, in which case the read-only database object will be closed and the read/write object will be returned in the future. "

Comment: Nice find and would go some way to preventing a failure on the first point I mention in my answer.

Comment: @Manfred Moser As said in my answer.... not sure if we can prove this one way or other (i.e. has/hasn't got perf advantage). Here is one (unverified) reason I can think that this could have a perf impact. If you use getWritableDatabase() you need to call close() method or else you get lots of red in LogCat. Wherein (this part is unverified) getReadableDatabase() doesn't mandate the call to method close(). If your application is closing the database often, this could(!) affect the performance.